# How can one flatten a cypher result to show summary data in columns?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the rank (say 1 to 103) and count of nodes for each rank in a cypher.

```
day.name    rank    count
12/14/2016  1   1
12/14/2016  2   2
12/14/2016  3   3
12/14/2016  4   10
...
12/14/2016  11  20000
12/14/2016  12  20500
...
12/14/2016  21  15000
12/14/2016  22  15000
```

I'd like to display in columns summary data such as count that was in rank 1 to 3, rank 4 to 10, etc.

In this example, the desired result would be

```
'rank_1_to_3'           'rank_4_to_10'      'rank_11_to_20' 'rank_21_to_100'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6                       10                   40500             30000
```

Here's the Cypher:

```
match (d:Domain {name:'hotelguides.com'}) 
match (c:Temp {name:"top30k_rank_1_to_100"}) 
match (day:Day {name:'2016-12-22'}) 
match (day)-[]-(kua:KeywordURLAssociation)-[]-(d) 
match (k:Keyword)-[]-(kua)-[]-(r:Rank) 
with day, kua, r, k  return day.name, r.name, count(k)
```

Comment: Could you please format the question appropriately?

Comment: @JFMeier - I took care of the formatting. :)

Comment: Lulu - there's no way to answer your question, as you haven't shown what your data looks like in Neo4j, or any cypher queries (you just showed tabular data, and there's no way to know how that maps to nodes and relationships). Please edit your question to provide more info; otherwise this is just a guessing game.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  Here's the cypher:
match (d:Domain {name:'hotelguides.com'}) match (c:Temp {name:"top30k_rank_1_to_100"})   match (day:Day {name:'2016-12-22'}) match (day)-[]-(kua:KeywordURLAssociation)-[]-(d) match (k:Keyword)-[]-(kua)-[]-(r:Rank)  with day, kua, r,k limit 100 return d.id, r.name, count(k)

Comment: @LuluLin you really need to *edit your question* - what you posted, in your comment, is unreadable. I've already taken the time to format your original question. You need to do the same with your additional content.

Comment: @David Makogon - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can get you started. I will leave applying it to your particular domain up to you. Essentially, you can use `filter` to filter a collection of results into another collection with a subset of those results.  With each smaller result you can use `reduce` to summarize that collection. Something like this..

```
with [
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:1, count:1},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:2, count:2},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:3, count:3},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:4, count:10},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:11, count:20000},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:12, count:20500},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:21, count:15000},
  {name:'12/14/2016', rank:22, count:15000}
] as days
return reduce(sum_c=0, d in filter(d in days where d.rank < 4) | sum_c + d.count) as rank_1_3
, reduce(sum_c=0, d in filter(d in days where d.rank > 3 and d.rank < 11) | sum_c + d.count) as rank_4_to_10
, reduce(sum_c=0, d in filter(d in days where d.rank > 10 and d.rank < 21) | sum_c + d.count) as rank_11_to_20
, reduce(sum_c=0, d in filter(d in days where d.rank > 20 and d.rank < 101) | sum_c + d.count) as rank_21_100
```